# Magento core_url_rewrite table still changing

Tags: sql, magento, url, url-rewriting

I see in database that core_url_rewrite table is changing all the time. When I open this table there is about ~147 000 rows, I refresh table 5secs after and there is about 155 000 rows, next 160t, and 127t... etc. Number of rows are changing in loop from ~120 000 - ~160 000. is that normal?

Comment: when this is happening is any one of your developers is working on the admin panel side??

Comment: Are you running any reindexing process?

Comment: any other reindexing process isn't running and no one is working on admin panel ;/

Comment: Is it still going? I think it will stop eventually. Unfortunately Magento rewrites remain problematic. I think you have had difficulty because many re-indexes have been queued up. Re-index once and wait a *long* time for it to finish. Turn off automatic re-indexing.